# How to download source code by specific change set number in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, changeset

```
node{
    stage('Source Control Management'){
    checkout([
        $class: 'TeamFoundationServerScm', 
        credentialsConfigurer: [
            $class: 'AutomaticCredentialsConfigurer'
        ],
        projectPath: '$/Onprem/Source/Service',
        serverUrl: 'http://abcd/',
        useOverwrite: true,
        useUpdate: true,
        workspaceName: 'Hudson-${JOB_NAME}-${NODE_NAME}'
    ])
    }
}
```

This pipeline script checkout the latest code whose chain set no is: 921
I want the pipeline to checkout only the previous code with chain set no: 917
What to do?

Comment: Are you using Azure DevOps and Team Foundation Server Plugin for Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

The [plugin README](https://github.com/jenkinsci/tfs-plugin#checkout-by-label-new-since-version-320) says this available and describes how to do it for a Freestyle job:[Use a versionspec argument to specify affected versions of items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/use-team-foundation-version-control-commands?view=azure-devops#use-a-versionspec-argument-to-specify-affected-versions-of-items). Confirmed this works in a Freestyle job, but not a pipeline. Also, only works if supplied a Build Parameter, not as a regular parameter; odd.

Comment: Yes, for freestyle it is working but for pipeline project it is not.